# Sum() on Multiple table was wrong result

Tags: mysql

I try Query but the result always same, please help me find out what wrong in my query

**Penjualan**

```
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|  oid   |    client      | qty  | b_digital  | b_large  | b_kotak  | b_laminate  | b_potong  | no_invoice  |  invoice_date  |
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| 41468  | Budi           |  19  |      6000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |      500  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41467  | Budi           |   6  |      4000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41466  | Budi           |   1  |      5500  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41524  | mega Utama     |   1  |      5500  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125640  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
| 41523  | Berkah Surya   |  24  |      4000  |       0  |       0  |        750  |        0  |     125638  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
| 41522  | Maximize Play  |   2  |     10000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125639  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

**Pelunasan**

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
| pid  | no_invoice  |    pay_date     | tot_pay |
+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|   1  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 9:40   |    2500 |
|   2  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 9:41   |    5000 |
|   3  |     125640  | 9/7/2015 10:31  |    2000 |
|   4  |     125639  | 9/7/2015 10:31  |    5000 |
|   5  |     125639  | 9/7/2015 10:31  |    2000 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

**Result Query (WRONG RESULT)**

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| no_invoice  |    client      | subtotal  | tgl_invoice  | total_byr  | tgl_bayar |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|     125640  | mega Utama     |     5500  | 9/7/2015     | 2000       | 9/7/2015  |
|     125639  | Maximize Play  |    20000  | 9/7/2015     | 7000       | 9/7/2015  |
|     125638  | Berkah Surya   |   114000  | 9/7/2015     | NULL       | NULL      |
|     125596  | Budi           |   153000  | 9/7/2015     | 22500      | 9/7/2015  |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Result I want (CORRECT RESULT)**

```
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|  oid   |    client      | qty  | b_digital  | b_large  | b_kotak  | b_laminate  | b_potong  | no_invoice  |  invoice_date  |
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| 41468  | Budi           |  19  |      6000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |      500  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41467  | Budi           |   6  |      4000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41466  | Budi           |   1  |      5500  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125596  | 9/7/2015 11:00 |
| 41524  | mega Utama     |   1  |      5500  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125640  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
| 41523  | Berkah Surya   |  24  |      4000  |       0  |       0  |        750  |        0  |     125638  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
| 41522  | Maximize Play  |   2  |     10000  |       0  |       0  |          0  |        0  |     125639  | 9/7/2015 8:00  |
+--------+----------------+------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

here SQL data : https://userscloud.com/mep01cocf2bt

```
SELECT penjualan.no_invoice, penjualan.client, (
                sum(penjualan.qty * ( penjualan.b_digital + penjualan.b_large + penjualan.b_kotak + penjualan.b_laminate + penjualan.b_potong )
                )) AS subtotal, LEFT( penjualan.invoice_date, 10 ) AS tgl_invoice, total_byr,tgl_bayar
                FROM penjualan
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT penjualan.no_invoice,
                sum(pelunasan.tot_pay) AS total_byr
                FROM penjualan, pelunasan
                WHERE penjualan.no_invoice=pelunasan.no_invoice
                GROUP BY pelunasan.no_invoice) AS ijin
                ON penjualan.no_invoice=ijin.no_invoice
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT penjualan.no_invoice,
                left(pelunasan.pay_date, 10) AS tgl_bayar
                FROM penjualan, pelunasan
                WHERE penjualan.no_invoice=pelunasan.no_invoice
                GROUP BY penjualan.no_invoice) AS tgl_bayar
                ON penjualan.no_invoice=tgl_bayar.no_invoice
                WHERE penjualan.no_invoice !=  ''
                AND LEFT( penjualan.invoice_date, 10 ) =  '2015-09-07'
                GROUP BY penjualan.no_invoice
                ORDER BY penjualan.no_invoice DESC
```

the problem at "total_byr"

Comment: Don't post code or data as images, inline them in the body of the question *as text*. Otherwise not only can nobody search, nobody can copy portions out to play with it.

Comment: Also - the real problem - "doesn't work" is not an explanation of the problem. What is the result you are getting, what do you expect, and why do you expect it?

Comment: the query is work but the result of "total_byr" was wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.no_invoice, a.client, 
    (sum(a.qty*(a.b_digital+a.b_large+a.b_kotak+a.b_laminate+a.b_potong))) AS subtotal, 
    date_format(a.invoice_date,'%d/%m/%Y') as tgl_invoice,
    (select sum(b.tot_pay) from pelunasan as b where b.no_invoice=a.no_invoice) as total_byr,
    (select distinct date_format(c.pay_date,'%d/%m/%Y') from pelunasan as c where c.no_invoice=a.no_invoice) as tgl_bayar
from penjualan as a
group by a.no_invoice
order by a.no_invoice desc
```